# Anadir texto a carrusel con js

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Tengo un carrusel corrusel
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero, he programado el siguiente js para obtener su valor y luego añadirlos de bajo de la imagen con una etiqueta `<p></p>`

```
let items = document.querySelector('.portfolop-lodging ');



for(i = 0; i < items.childElementCount; i++){
   item =items.childNodes[i];
   title = item.querySelector('.slick-track .widget-title a').text;
   subTitle = item.querySelector('.slick-track .entry-tags ul li a').text;
   content = item.querySelector('.work-cover');

  p1 = document.createElement('p');
  p2 = document.createElement('p');

  t = document.createTextNode(title);
  b = document.createTextNode(subTitle);

  p1.appendChild(t);
  p2.appendChild(b);
  content.appendChild(p1);
  content.appendChild(p2);

}
```

al colocarlo directamente desde la consola del navegador funciona, pero luego a cargarlo desde el archivo me nuestra el siguiente error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childElementCount' of null`

```
 <div id="dfd-portfolio" class="portfolop-lodging">
  <div class="recent-works-list  slick-initialized slick-slider">
   <div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list draggable">
    <div class="slick-track" role="listbox" style="opacity: 1; width: 1352px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
     <div class="recent-works-item project portfolio-hover-style-22 slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-category=" cabanas"
      data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide00" style="width: 338px;">
        <div class="work-cover">
         <div class="entry-thumb">
          <img src="./img/cabaña2-600x550.png" alt="Rancho Paraíso">
          <div class="portfolio-entry-hover">
            <div class="title-wrap">
              <h6 class="widget-title">
                <a href="#" tabindex="0">Rancho Paraíso</a>
              </h6>

              <div class="entry-tags">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#" tabindex="0">Cabañas</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>

              </div>
            </div>
            <a data-rel="prettyPhoto[184015acf55b451e08]" class="zoom-post" href="http://atemajacdebrizuela.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/cabaña2.png"
              tabindex="0">
              <i class="dfd-icon-zoom"></i>
            </a>
            <a data-rel="prettyPhoto[iframe]" class="quick-view" href="http://atemajacdebrizuela.com/?my-product=rancho-paraiso?iframe=true&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=100%25"
              tabindex="0">
              <span class="quick-view-text chaffle" data-lang="en">Quick view</span>
            </a>
            <a class="open-post" href="http://atemajacdebrizuela.com/?my-product=rancho-paraiso" tabindex="0">
              <i class="dfd-icon-link"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="plus-link" href="http://atemajacdebrizuela.com/?my-product=rancho-paraiso" tabindex="0">
              <span class="plus-link-container">
                <span class="plus-link-out"></span>
                <span class="plus-link-come"></span>
              </span>
            </a>
            <a class="dfd-dotted-link" href="http://atemajacdebrizuela.com/?my-product=rancho-paraiso" tabindex="0">
              <span class="dfd-left-line"></span>
              <span></span>
              <span class="dfd-right-line"></span>
            </a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, podrias poner el html que estas contando?.

Comment: Creo que ya se que puede ser tu error, en vez de esta linea `let items = document.querySelector('.portfolop-lodging ');` , pon esta `let items = document.getElementsByClassName('portfolop-lodging');`

Comment: Ya coloque el HTML. voy a probar con la `document.getElementsByClassName('portfolop-lodging');`

Answer (score 0):

si funciona desde la consola y no desde el html es probablemente porque aún no existe en el DOM el elemento al que apuntas.

Wordpress viene con jQuery precargado, prueba englobar tu javascript en el evento de cuando la página termina de cargar.

```
$(function(){
   // Aquí el código

});
```

Comment: No, igual, sigue apareciendo en mismo error

Comment: está en un <script></script> justo debajo del </body> ?

Comment: si el js esta al final del body

Comment: entonces puede ser el plugin que crea el slider que está fuera de tiempo, prueba este plugin https://github.com/pie6k/jquery.initialize (se queda esperando que aparezca en el DOM el elemento que le decís y ejecuta una función)

Answer (score 0):

Probando por ahi tienes que cambiar la linea

```
let items = document.querySelector('.portfolop-lodging ');
```

por

```
var items = document.getElementById('dfd-portfolio').childElementCount;
```

> NOTA: La expresión `let` es no-estandar por lo tanto hay tener cuidado al usarla.Para mas detalle ver este [Sitio](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let).

Comment: de hecho ya no debería usarse. por lo que dice la documentación que puse ahí.